# Local Storage mock not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am testing an application in which API is called if an item in localStorage exists. So I mocked the localStorage everything is working fine for the first test case but seems to fail in the second case even though both tests are the same.

test.tsx

```
describe("Test",()=>{

beforeEach(()=>{
localStorageMock={
   getItem:jest.fn().mockImpementaton(()=>{
     return JSON.stringify({
       id:'123'
     )}
    }),
   setItem:jest.fn()
}
Object.defineProperty(window,'localStorage',{value: localStorageMock});
})
test("First",()=>{
  console.log(localStorage.getItem());
  //output '{'id':'123'}'
})
test("Second",()=>{
  console.log(localStorage.getItem());
  //output undefined
})
})
```

Comment: What happens if you reset the storage to oringal storage as in `afterEach` or instead of using `beforeEach`, use `beforeAll`

Comment: I used spyOn and now it works.